# Decreasing performance for excel com object in powershell script

Tags: performance, excel, object, powershell, com

I have witten a powershell script that creates an excel com object to repeatedly read *.csv files, generate a graph, and then save the the graph as a *.pdf file.  The code segment is shown below.  When the script starts, it takes between 2-4 seconds per file.  The longer the script runs, the longer it takes to process an individual csv file.  After about 1,000 files, it takes about 60 seconds per file.  All of the csv files are small 2 columns by 70 rows.  When I have 215 graphs to generate, it takes about 12 minutes to run.  When I have 1,522 graphs, it takes over 20 hours.  Is there something I can do to speed this up?

Tia,
  Mark K.

```
#
#  Create an Excell object and use it to generate the graphs.  
#

$ex = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$chartType = "microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlChartType" -as [type]
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]
$ex.DisplayAlerts = $False
$ex.Visible = $False
$wb = $ex.Workbooks.Add()
$ws = $wb.worksheets
$ws1 = $ws.Item(1)

try {                                            # Delete unneeded worksheets, if present
   $ws.item(3).delete()
   $ws.item(2).delete()
}
catch [Exception] {
   Out-Null
}

$i = 0

foreach ($p in $pdfs) {                       # $p is a csv file to be the source for a pdf

    Try {
        $ws1.Name = $p.Substring(0,$p.IndexOf('.'))
        $Connector = ("text;http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/" + $lpar + "/" + $p) 
        $CellRef = $ws1.Range("A1")
        $Conn = $ws1.QueryTables.Add($Connector,$CellRef)
        $ws1.QueryTables.item($Conn.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $True
        $ws1.QueryTables.item($Conn.name).TextFileParseType = 1
        $ws1.QueryTables.item($Conn.name).Refresh() | Out-Null
        $ws2 = $ex.charts.add()
        $ws2.chartType = $chartType::xlLine
        $ws2.Name = $ws1.Name + " Graph"
        $ws2.HasTitle = $True
        $ws2.ChartTitle.Text = $ws1.Range("A1").text
        $Data = $ws1.range("b2:b71")
        $ws2.setSourceData($Data) | Out-Null
        $ws2.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = $ws1.Range("A2:A71")
        $wb.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF,"$drive`:\captrendGraphs\$lpar\" + $ws1.Name + ".pdf",0,$True,$True,1,1)
        $ws2.Delete() | Out-Null
        $ws1.UsedRange.ClearContents() | Out-Null
    }
    catch [Exception] {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.toString()
        Write-Log $($_.Exception.toString())
        Write-Host $_.Exception.message
        Write-Log $($_.Exception.message)
        Write-Host $_.Exception.source
        Write-Log $($_.Exception.source)
        Write-Host $_.Exception.StackTrace
        Write-Log $($_.Exception.StackTrace)
        Write-Host "Error occured with: " $p
        Write-Log $("Error occured with: " + $p)
    }

    $i++
    $rptP = $("{0:D4}" -f $i + " " + $p)
    Write-Host $rptP
    Write-Log $rptP
}
```

Comment: Try creating a new Com object for each file.  This way you can dispose of the file and let the garbage collector clean it up.  Otherwise, you are repeatedly using the same session and making all these changes in memory.

Comment: Terminating & re-creating the Excel COM object is also expensive (in terms of time) - about 54 seconds to do it 100 times on my system (with no other work performed). Try creating (and "closing") a new workbook for each iteration of the loop first.

Comment: The reason this is expensive is due to uncontrolled data growth, such as cell formatting, undo data and query tables that are not propertly disposed. It might also be that PowerShell isn't very efficient at releasing COM interface pointers, you could use `$Conn` directly instead of `$ws1.QueryTables.item($Conn.name)`. But in general, can you just create a new worksheet and delete the previous? That would probably save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: First, I tried creating a new workbook per file/graph. That ran faster but it would blow up somewhere over 600 files due to memory issues (as far as I can tell).  Then I tried creating a new sheet per file/graph and that worked well, what use to take 20 hrs. now takes about 1.25 hrs.  The Excel process still gradually uses more memory but not enough to fail, at least so far.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly open and close a new excel session in time intervals (15 mins) or graph creation intervals (every 1000) and see if that helps some.